# How to make a form change color dependent on app setting overriding css

Tags: css, asp.net

We have a situation where a bunch of users (we have no idea which ones or how many, could be dozens) have got ahold of the development environment URL for our ASP.NET application and are using it thinking it is production.

In the past we just had a redirect in the default page of dev to send them to production but now we need to be using our dev environment for development.  Trouble is that if we take away the redirect we have users who eventually call to complain that "the data is wrong" or "my changes are being overwritten", etc.  We have sent those we knew about the correct URL and instructed them to use it but some of them are relapsing (probably because they have bookmarks they didn't think to change).

What I would like to do is have some unmistakable visual change that will jump out at them and which they *can't* *miss* telling them that they are not in the correct application.  My preference would be to turn the screen bright green in development and have a link which would be invisible in production, which would take them to production.

My team lead is pushing back.  First he said that just looking at the URL in the browser should be good enough (yeah, right, *that'll* work) and then he said we can't change color because we are using style sheets so overriding them based on an app setting in the config file (which we already have) would be too much work.

I don't know enough about web development to argue the point (my background is Winforms) but I was hoping someone might point me in the right direction to figure out how to make the form change color regardless of what value is in the css file.  Or have another suggestion for a very attention getting visual change that could be controlled from a config setting.

Comment: In terms of the visual change you're seeking for the development environment, it can only be controlled from a config file? It can't be managed from the HTML or CSS files?

Comment: We have different config files for development, staging and production.  Using the Microsoft push-button easy publishing so we never have to worry about getting the wrong web.config to the wrong environment.  The web.config file is the only file which is not identical in all environments.  So that file is the only way a page can know which environment it is in.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with the applications you mention. In case it helps, however, you can override a CSS stylesheet by applying inline styles to the HTML elements directly. So for instance, if you wanted to change the background color of a form (overriding the color in the stylesheet) you would write: `<form style="background-color: lawngreen !important" ...>`. The `!important` declaration simply gives the rule even higher priority, but may not be necessary.

Comment: why not just inform them that the link they access is the development one, and just give the production link

Comment: Euphoria, that would work if we knew every time anyone was using the development link, but we do not.  Often we find out only after a week or two (or more) of them using the wrong link.  This is because we have a nightly backup which synchronizes our production and development databases, so the data is usually the same in both databases.  There is no indicator to them that they are in the wrong place.  And even when we give them the production link they occasionally use the wrong one because of bookmarks.

Comment: Michael_B, if I had this in my production web.config: <add key="CurEnv" value="Production"/> and this in dev: <add key="CurEnv" value="Development"/>, how would I set the form's background color based on the value in the config file?  (If you can answer, please do so with an answer so I can accept it)

Comment: Hi Francine, This is interesting. I'm looking into it. I'll get back to you shortly. (Also, when posting comments, you need to prefix a user name with @ in order to notify the user that you posted a comment. Otherwise they won't know. I just happened to drop by ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using ASP.Net Forms here and not ASP.Net MVC Razor Views.

In your config file, set an Application Setting which states the environment the application is running in:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="DEV" />
</appSettings>
```

Then you can use config transforms to have the value of this setting change per environment. See this link for how these work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Assuming that you want the background color of every page in the app to change based on which environment the app is running in, then in your HTML (we have this in our .Master pages) add a server-side call to a helper function which will set the CSS Class based on which environment the application is running in:

```
<body class="<%= Helpers.GetDeploymentEnvironment()%>">
```

You'll also need to link the Environment.css file which holds the environment specific styles:

```
<head>
    <link href="~/css/Environment.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Here is an example of the Helper functions which retrieve the Environment setting from config (this is in VB.Net, if you need C# versions comment below and i'll update the answer):

```
Public Shared Function GetDeploymentEnvironment() As String
    Dim environmentSetting = GetAppSetting("Environment")
    Return environmentSetting
End Function

Public Shared Function GetAppSetting(ByVal strConfigName As String) As String
    If ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(strConfigName) IsNot Nothing Then
        Return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(strConfigName).ToString()
    End If
    Return String.Empty
End Function
```

The Environment.css file with the styles per environment

```
/* CSS Styling for deployment environment */

/* No background-color for PROD */

body.LOCAL {
    background-color: #f6f66c; /* Yellow Local build */
}
body.DEV {
    background-color: #ffe4e1; /* Misty Rose DEV */
}
body.TEST {
    background-color: #e6e6fa; /* Lavender TEST */
}
```

Finally, if you want a link to appear somewhere in all pages of the app, but not if the app is running in Production, then use a server-side hyperlink and set its visibility in the Page_Load method, based on the return value of your helper function:

In your .aspx:

```
<body class="<%= Helpers.GetDeploymentEnvironment()%>">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypProduction" NavigateUrl="http://your.prod.server/page.aspx" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</body>
```

In your code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    hypProduction.Visible = Helpers.GetDeploymentEnvironment() = "PROD"
End Sub
```

But i'd recommend putting "PROD" in some Constants.vb file, rather than relying on a 'magic string'.